# gnu makefile how to manage 3 parametr from patsubst

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to write a simple makefile to launch a program. This program need two input parameter and An output which depend on input file
I have all the inputs on RAW/ directory. The basename of the file are  the same but I need two files  *R1* and *R2*.

```
    RDIR=RAW
    OUTDIR=FINAL
    RFILES:=$(wildcard $(RDIR)/*_R1_001.fastq.gz)

    OUTFILE=$(patsubst %_R1_001.fastq.gz,%_R2_001.fastq.gz,$(RFILES))
    OUTKAL=$(patsubst $(RDIR)/%_R1_001.fastq.gz,$(OUTDIR)/%,$(RFILES))
    .PHONY: clean all

    all: $(OUTFILE) $(RFILES) $(OUTDIR) $(OUTKAL)
    $(OUTFILE): $(RFILES)
        -echo $ FINAL/A
       -echo  "tools -i " $"  $@



    $(OUTDIR):
        mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)


    clean::
        $(RM) -rf $(OUTDIR)
```

What is the simple way to do  a comand like this

```
`tools  A_R1_001.fastq.gz -b "A_R2_001.fastq.gz" > FINAL/A`
```

So how can combine this patsubst?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$(OUTFILE): $(RFILES)
    ...
```

is the wrong construction. It makes *all* input files prerequisites of *each* output file. Also, you seem to intend to build `FINAL/A`, but this rule tells Make that its purpose is to build `RAW/A_R2_001.fastq.gz`, which will cause problems.

What we need is something like:

```
FINAL/A: RAW/A_R1_001.fastq.gz $(OUTDIR)
    tools A_R1_001.fastq.gz -b "A_R2_001.fastq.gz" > FINAL/A
```

but for all input files. So we write a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) which uses [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
FINAL/%: RAW/%_R1_001.fastq.gz $(OUTDIR)
    tools $*_R1_001.fastq.gz -b "$*_R2_001.fastq.gz" > $@
```

Then we simplify the `all` rule:

```
all: $(OUTKAL)
```

and we're done.